# How do I do a grouped pivot_longer

Tags: r, pivot

I am struggline to wrangle my data and tranform it into a long format.
I want to pivot the below columns

```
cols_to_pivot
 [1] "Walk_Clin_M"     "Walk_Clin_SD"    "Walk_Cont_M"     "Walk_Cont_SD"    "Walk_Clin_SE"    "Walk_Cont_SE"    "Walk_d"          "Sit_Clin_M"      "Sit_Clin_SD"     "Sit_Cont_M"     
[11] "Sit_Cont_SD"     "Sit_Clin_SE"     "Sit_Cont_SE"     "Sit_d"           "Stand_Clin_M"    "Stand_Clin_SD"   "Stand_Cont_M"    "Stand_Cont_SD"   "Stand_Clin_SE"   "Stand_Cont_SE"  
[21] "Stand_d"         "Head_Clin_M"     "Head_Clin_SD"    "Head_Cont_M"     "Head_Cont_SD"    "Heah_Clin_SE"    "Head_Cont_SE"    "Head_d"          "roll_Clin_M"     "roll_Clin_SD"   
[31] "roll_Cont_M"     "roll_Cont_SD"    "roll_Clin_SE"    "roll_Cont_SE"    "roll_d"          "standWH_Clin_M"  "standWH_Clin_SD" "standWH_Cont_M"  "standWH_Cont_SD" "standWH_Clin_SE"
[41] "standWH_Cont_SE" "standWH_d"       "climb_Clin_M"    "climb_Clin_SD"   "climb_Cont_M"    "climb_Cont_SD"   "climb_Clin_SE"   "climb_Cont_SE"   "climb_d"         "walkWH_Clin_M"  
[51] "walkWH_Clin_SD"  "walkWH_Cont_M"   "walkWH_Cont_SD"  "walkWH_Clin_SE"  "walkWH_Cont_SE"  "walkWH_d"        "crawl_Clin_M"    "crawl_Clin_SD"   "crawl_Cont_M"    "crawl_Cont_SD"  
[61] "crawl_Clin_SE"   "crawl_Cont_SE"   "crawl_d"
```

But group them by name, such as "Walk" so that each group of columns is pivoted, and I have new column names "Clin_M", "Clin_SD", "Cont_M" ...etc with the values.

here is a sample of the data

```
         Study.ID Year Clin_Tot Cont_Tot less20 Disorder.Group subgroup Design SE extract ES.Calc missing both Walk_Clin_M Walk_Clin_SD Walk_Cont_M Walk_Cont_SD Walk_Clin_SE Walk_Cont_SE
1      Comings 1987 1987      347       47      0           Tics     <NA>      2  0       0       0       0    1       14.04         1.61       11.76         1.25           NA           NA
2        Jones 1994 1994       30     4716      0          Schiz     <NA>      2  0       0       1       1    1          NA           NA       13.50         2.40           NA           NA
3    Chawarska 2007 2007       51       NA      0            ASD     <NA>      2  0       0       0       0    0       13.50         2.50          NA           NA           NA           NA
4  Gernsbacher 2008 2008      172       44      0            ASD     <NA>      2  0       0       0       0    0          NA           NA          NA           NA           NA           NA
5          Kim 2008 2008       32       NA      0            ASD     <NA>      2  0       0       0       0    0       12.40         2.80          NA           NA           NA           NA
6      Ozonoff 2008 2008       26       24      0            ASD    AutNR      2  1       0       0       0    1       13.44           NA       10.90           NA         0.57         0.36
7      Ozonoff 2008 2008       28       24      0            ASD   AutNR       2  1       0       0       0    1       12.17           NA       10.90           NA         0.46         0.36
8       Matson 2010 2010      331       NA      0            ASD     comb      2  0       0       0       0    0       13.88         3.74          NA           NA           NA           NA
9       Matson 2010 2010      165       NA      0            ASD       AD      2  0       0       0       0    0       14.17         3.73          NA           NA           NA           NA
10      Matson 2010 2010      166       NA      0            ASD      PDD      2  0       0       0       0    0       13.75         3.56          NA           NA           NA           NA
11    Sorensen 2010 2010       92     4982      0          Schiz     <NA>      1  0       0       0       0    1       13.01         2.88       11.71         1.47           NA           NA
12         Liu 2012 2012       26       61      0            ASD       AD      2  0       0       1       1    0          NA           NA          NA           NA           NA           NA
13         Liu 2012 2012       18       61      1            ASD       AS      2  0       0       1       1    0          NA           NA          NA           NA           NA           NA
    Walk_d Sit_Clin_M Sit_Clin_SD Sit_Cont_M Sit_Cont_SD Sit_Clin_SE Sit_Cont_SE   Sit_d Stand_Clin_M Stand_Clin_SD Stand_Cont_M Stand_Cont_SD Stand_Clin_SE Stand_Cont_SE Stand_d
1       NA         NA          NA         NA          NA          NA          NA      NA           NA            NA           NA            NA            NA            NA      NA
2   0.5144         NA          NA         NA          NA          NA          NA      NA           NA            NA           NA            NA            NA            NA      NA
3       NA         NA          NA         NA          NA          NA          NA      NA           NA            NA           NA            NA            NA            NA      NA
4       NA         NA          NA         NA          NA          NA          NA      NA           NA            NA           NA            NA            NA            NA      NA
5       NA         NA          NA         NA          NA          NA          NA      NA           NA            NA           NA            NA            NA            NA      NA
6       NA       6.80          NA       5.17          NA        0.77        0.32      NA           NA            NA           NA            NA            NA            NA      NA
7       NA       5.91          NA       5.17          NA        0.27        0.32      NA           NA            NA           NA            NA            NA            NA      NA
8       NA         NA          NA         NA          NA          NA          NA      NA           NA            NA           NA            NA            NA            NA      NA
9       NA         NA          NA         NA          NA          NA          NA      NA           NA            NA           NA            NA            NA            NA      NA
10      NA         NA          NA         NA          NA          NA          NA      NA           NA            NA           NA            NA            NA            NA      NA
11      NA       7.18        1.69       6.85        1.49          NA          NA      NA        10.61          1.86        10.29          1.55            NA            NA      NA
12 12.2258         NA          NA         NA          NA          NA          NA 17.1133           NA            NA           NA            NA            NA            NA 13.7335
13 13.5994         NA          NA         NA          NA          NA          NA 13.5458           NA            NA           NA            NA            NA            NA 14.2968
   Head_Clin_M Head_Clin_SD Head_Cont_M Head_Cont_SD Heah_Clin_SE Head_Cont_SE  Head_d roll_Clin_M roll_Clin_SD roll_Cont_M roll_Cont_SD roll_Clin_SE roll_Cont_SE  roll_d standWH_Clin_M
1           NA           NA          NA           NA           NA           NA      NA          NA           NA          NA           NA           NA           NA      NA             NA
2           NA           NA          NA           NA           NA           NA      NA          NA           NA          NA           NA           NA           NA      NA             NA
3           NA           NA          NA           NA           NA           NA      NA          NA           NA          NA           NA           NA           NA      NA             NA
4           NA           NA          NA           NA           NA           NA      NA          NA           NA          NA           NA           NA           NA      NA             NA
5           NA           NA          NA           NA           NA           NA      NA          NA           NA          NA           NA           NA           NA      NA             NA
6           NA           NA          NA           NA           NA           NA      NA        5.10           NA        3.82           NA         0.62         0.32      NA             NA
7           NA           NA          NA           NA           NA           NA      NA        4.15           NA        3.82           NA         0.28         0.32      NA             NA
8           NA           NA          NA           NA           NA           NA      NA          NA           NA          NA           NA           NA           NA      NA             NA
9           NA           NA          NA           NA           NA           NA      NA          NA           NA          NA           NA           NA           NA      NA             NA
10          NA           NA          NA           NA           NA           NA      NA          NA           NA          NA           NA           NA           NA      NA             NA
11        1.08         0.75        0.87         0.59           NA           NA      NA        5.85         1.77        5.82         1.75           NA           NA      NA           8.83
12          NA           NA          NA           NA           NA           NA 17.0328          NA           NA          NA           NA           NA           NA 15.0211             NA
13          NA           NA          NA           NA           NA           NA 19.3396          NA           NA          NA           NA           NA           NA 14.5919             NA
   standWH_Clin_SD standWH_Cont_M standWH_Cont_SD standWH_Clin_SE standWH_Cont_SE standWH_d climb_Clin_M climb_Clin_SD climb_Cont_M climb_Cont_SD climb_Clin_SE climb_Cont_SE climb_d
1               NA             NA              NA              NA              NA        NA           NA            NA           NA            NA            NA            NA      NA
2               NA             NA              NA              NA              NA        NA           NA            NA           NA            NA            NA            NA      NA
3               NA             NA              NA              NA              NA        NA           NA            NA           NA            NA            NA            NA      NA
4               NA             NA              NA              NA              NA        NA           NA            NA           NA            NA            NA            NA      NA
5               NA             NA              NA              NA              NA        NA           NA            NA           NA            NA            NA            NA      NA
6               NA             NA              NA              NA              NA        NA           NA            NA           NA            NA            NA            NA      NA
7               NA             NA              NA              NA              NA        NA           NA            NA           NA            NA            NA            NA      NA
8               NA             NA              NA              NA              NA        NA           NA            NA           NA            NA            NA            NA      NA
9               NA             NA              NA              NA              NA        NA           NA            NA           NA            NA            NA            NA      NA
10              NA             NA              NA              NA              NA        NA           NA            NA           NA            NA            NA            NA      NA
11            2.26           8.52            1.79              NA              NA        NA           NA            NA           NA            NA            NA            NA      NA
12              NA             NA              NA              NA              NA   17.9716           NA            NA           NA            NA            NA            NA 24.5702
13              NA             NA              NA              NA              NA   13.8677           NA            NA           NA            NA            NA            NA 16.6841
   walkWH_Clin_M walkWH_Clin_SD walkWH_Cont_M walkWH_Cont_SD walkWH_Clin_SE walkWH_Cont_SE walkWH_d crawl_Clin_M crawl_Clin_SD crawl_Cont_M crawl_Cont_SD crawl_Clin_SE crawl_Cont_SE
1             NA             NA            NA             NA             NA             NA       NA           NA            NA           NA            NA            NA            NA
2             NA             NA            NA             NA             NA             NA       NA           NA            NA           NA            NA            NA            NA
3             NA             NA            NA             NA             NA             NA       NA           NA            NA           NA            NA            NA            NA
4             NA             NA            NA             NA             NA             NA       NA           NA            NA           NA            NA            NA            NA
5             NA             NA            NA             NA             NA             NA       NA         8.50          2.50           NA            NA            NA            NA
6             NA             NA            NA             NA             NA             NA       NA         8.31            NA         6.80            NA          0.52           0.2
7             NA             NA            NA             NA             NA             NA       NA         7.32            NA         6.80            NA          0.42           0.2
8             NA             NA            NA             NA             NA             NA       NA         9.35          3.82           NA            NA            NA            NA
9             NA             NA            NA             NA             NA             NA       NA         9.87          4.20           NA            NA            NA            NA
10            NA             NA            NA             NA             NA             NA       NA         8.86          3.36           NA            NA            NA            NA
11          10.1           2.02           9.9            1.5             NA             NA       NA         8.89          1.61         8.84          1.64            NA            NA
12            NA             NA            NA             NA             NA             NA  18.3203           NA            NA           NA            NA            NA            NA
13            NA             NA            NA             NA             NA             NA  14.3773           NA            NA           NA            NA            NA            NA
   crawl_d
1       NA
2       NA
3       NA
4       NA
5       NA
6       NA
7       NA
8       NA
9       NA
10      NA
11      NA
12 15.2625
13 14.9406
```

I've tried a few things but nothing has got me near as I cant get my head round how to code it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach, using a one-row example dataframe `df`:

```
df <- structure(list(Study.ID = "Comings", Year = 1987L, Clin_Tot = 1987L, 
    Cont_Tot = 347L, less20 = 47L, Disorder.Group = 0L, subgroup = "Tics", 
    Design = "<NA>", SE = 2L, extract = 0L, ES.Calc = 0L, missing = 0L, 
    both = 0L, Walk_Clin_M = 1L, Walk_Clin_SD = 14.04, Walk_Cont_M = 1.61, 
    Walk_Cont_SD = 11.76, Walk_Clin_SE = 1.25, Walk_Cont_SE = NA, 
    X = NA, Walk_d = NA, Sit_Clin_M = NA, Sit_Clin_SD = NA, Sit_Cont_M = NA, 
    Sit_Cont_SD = NA, Sit_Clin_SE = NA, Sit_Cont_SE = NA, Sit_d = NA, 
    Stand_Clin_M = NA, Stand_Clin_SD = NA, Stand_Cont_M = NA, 
    Stand_Cont_SD = NA, Stand_Clin_SE = NA, Stand_Cont_SE = NA, 
    Stand_d = NA, Head_Clin_M = NA, Head_Clin_SD = NA, Head_Cont_M = NA, 
    Head_Cont_SD = NA, Heah_Clin_SE = NA, Head_Cont_SE = NA, 
    Head_d = NA, roll_Clin_M = NA, roll_Clin_SD = NA, roll_Cont_M = NA, 
    roll_Cont_SD = NA, roll_Clin_SE = NA, roll_Cont_SE = NA, 
    roll_d = NA, standWH_Clin_M = NA, standWH_Clin_SD = NA, standWH_Cont_M = NA, 
    standWH_Cont_SD = NA, standWH_Clin_SE = NA, standWH_Cont_SE = NA, 
    standWH_d = NA, climb_Clin_M = NA, climb_Clin_SD = NA, climb_Cont_M = NA, 
    climb_Cont_SD = NA, climb_Clin_SE = NA, climb_Cont_SE = NA, 
    climb_d = NA, walkWH_Clin_M = NA, walkWH_Clin_SD = NA, walkWH_Cont_M = NA, 
    walkWH_Cont_SD = NA, walkWH_Clin_SE = NA, walkWH_Cont_SE = NA, 
    walkWH_d = NA, crawl_Clin_M = NA, crawl_Clin_SD = NA, crawl_Cont_M = NA, 
    crawl_Cont_SD = NA, crawl_Clin_SE = NA, crawl_Cont_SE = NA, 
    crawl_d = NA), class = "data.frame", row.names = 1L)
```

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df |>
    mutate(ID = row_number()) |>
    pivot_longer(cols = contains(c('_M', '_SE', '_SD', '_d')),
                 names_to = 'param',
                 values_to = 'value'
                 ) |>
    separate(param, into = c('move', 'clin_cont_stat'),
             sep = '_', 
             extra = 'merge'
             ) |>
    pivot_wider(names_from = clin_cont_stat, values_from = value)

``
```